# sys.indexes appears to be out of date

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a script to modify an index on a table. First I check the sys.indexes, sys.index_columns in a query to make sure the index has not already been modified (the columns are the same as I expect) and drop the index if it needs to be updated. I then create the index with the new structure if it does not exist. All of this appears to work fine and when I go to the object browser on my table and view the properties of the index everything looks good. However, when I query sys.indexes and sys.index_columns again it shows the structure from the OLD index. How can I get those tables updated? I assumed it would happen automatically when I created the index again after dropping it.

Comment: They should be. You might need to create a complete script the demonstrates the problem to get assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My query was wrong that was looking at sys.indexes.

I had this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.index_columns ic
  ON ic.index_id = i.index_id
  AND ic.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN sys.columns c
  ON c.object_id = i.object_id
  AND c.column_id = ic.index_column_id  --<--
WHERE i.name = 'Index002'
```

Which should have been this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.indexes i
JOIN sys.index_columns ic
  ON ic.index_id = i.index_id
  AND ic.object_id = i.object_id
JOIN sys.columns c
  ON c.object_id = i.object_id
  AND c.column_id = ic.column_id --<--
WHERE i.name = 'Index002'
```